# Shouldn't Synonymizer be a silver/gold badge?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, badges, tag-synonyms

I noticed that Synonymizer is only a bronze badge. Yet in order to obtain this badge you need to have 2500 reputation or more to even create tag synonyms. Then, on top of that you also need to be able to find a tag synonym.

Only 514 of these have been awarded... This makes the BRONZE badge Synonymizer rarer to have than most the gold medal badges. So my question is, why is this a bronze badge?

Comment: I think the real problem is that the tag synonym suggestion system isn't really working: the interface is deeply hidden and the voting requirements are too strict for relatively unpopular "long-tail" tags (which are the ones that actually need new synonyms, most of the time). As a result, it's very hard to get a synonym created, except by asking a mod to do it (or possibly by canvassing for eligible voters on chat).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Yet in order to obtain this badger you need to have 2500 reputation or more to even create tag synonyms. Then, on top of that you also need to be able to find a tag synonym.

How much reputation you have to get before being able to get a badge has no bearing on whether a badge should be silver (or gold, for that matter).

- You need 2000 reputation to review questions, but Custodian is still a bronze badge, and you still have to complete 250 reviews for a silver Reviewer badge.
- You also need 2000 reputation to be able to edit freely. *Then* you can rollback, but on top of that you need to be able to find a post needing rollback before you can get your bronze Cleanup badge.

... and so on for a few others.

It's a bronze badge because, [according to the badge page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges), it's the sort of thing bronze badges are:

> Bronze badgers encourage users to try out new features on the site. They are easy to get if you try!

It is not a significant achievement in the league of silver badges.

Comment: However, if we are quoting what the badge page says. "Silver badges are less common than bronze ones." and gold "They are rarely awarded." So how are silver less common than bronze when this bronze is this rare.

Comment: @Lain That's descriptive of what silver badges happen to be, not prescriptive; badges don't become silver _just because_ they're going to be rarer. Take a look at the silver badges that exist. They're all significant achievements requiring a lot of work or very high quality contributions. Tag synonyms are something you're unlikely to find, but that doesn't make creating one an achievement on the level of other silver badges.

Comment: You can, in principle, get Custodian for Suggested Edits at 1 rep by reviewing a suggestion on one of your own posts. I believe you can get Cleanup in much the same way, by rolling back an edit on one of your posts.